# Is it possible to change the logging.properties file without stopping Tomcat

Tags: java, logging, tomcat7, java.util.logging

I'd like to change the `$CATALINA/conf/logging.properties` file without stopping Tomcat 7 or any web application.

The need is for exemple to change the level of detection, or to add a Handler on a suspect class.

Is it also possible to do the same with `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/[myApp]/WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties` file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the reloadable attribute of Tomcat's Context element to false, the server will not require restart when it finds configuration changes while running.

Comment: Have you actually verified that? As far as I know is that JULI uses a JVM-wide conf file.

Comment: It works perfectly. Just notice that rules for /META-INF/context.xml has changed from tomcat 6 to 7. For simplicity, I've put reloadable directly in $CATALINA/conf/context.xml