# Reload tomcat7 logging at runtime

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, tomcat7, java.util.logging

Is it possible to reload ${catalina.home}/conf/logging.properties at run time and avoid restarting tomcat, same as we do in JBoss. Changes in the config file gets loaded automatically.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130820/is-it-possible-to-change-the-logging-properties-file-without-stopping-tomcat

Comment: Tried this before but it didn't work for me. Added the logging.properties to <WatchedResource /> but that causes all the wars to redeploy which I want to avoid.

Comment: You can follow this answer. [Reload tomcat7 logging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141249/reload-tomcat-logging-at-runtime)

Comment: Didn't work as well, when I am setting -Djava.util.logging.manager=java.util.logging.LogManager, it always throws ClassNotFoundException. I am using tomcat7